# Overwriting bot names and images with the same bot in different channels

Tags: discord.py

I have a discord bot in about 50 servers. I was wondering if it was possible for me to overwrite the bot username and image with the server that its in.
So for example my bot is called "My Bot" and has the image "MyBot.png"
Server 1 uses a command on my bot and it responds with the name "Their server" and the image "TheirServer.png"

I have seen some posts about being able to overwrite the bots name and image but I was just thinking if it was possible to do it on a per server basis.

Maybe an if server ID matches... then use this image and this name.

I am not 100% if that makes sense but let me know!

Comment: It is pretty straight forward to change the bot name to the guild name since nickname is a guild attribute. It seems like the bot image/avatar is a bot attribute and will be the same on all guilds.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible but changing bot username and image is 1 time process. if you change bot username and image again and again then you will get a warning as well as an error by discord.

You can use it but username and image once changed will show the same as in 1 server for all servers.